# Collations in a AggregationOperations

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, collation

I need to add to my aggregationOperation collations to be able to change my result from AAA BBB CCC AAA TO aaa BBB bbb CCC ccc, I found this.

```
new CreateCollectionOptions().collation(
                Collation.builder().locale("en_US").build()));
```

but the builder() does not find it as a value. Cannot resolve method 'builder' in 'Collation'

this is my actual code.

```
List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = new ArrayList<>();
        aggregationOperations.add(match(criteria));
        
        aggregationOperations.add(sort(orderBy.equals("asc")? Sort.Direction.ASC: Sort.Direction.DESC, sortField)
                .and(Sort.Direction.ASC,"_id"));
```